# Superior limit of $cos(nx)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Let $x$ be a  real number, and $({x}/{\pi})\notin \mathbb{Q}.$ Consider sequence $a_n=cos(nx),(n\in \mathbb{N}),$ then we can see that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ does not exit. But since $a_n$ is bounded, it has a superior limit and a  inferior limit. I guess that the superior limit of $a_n$ is a positive number and the inferior limit is $0$, but cannot prove it strictly.

**Question:** Prove that $$\displaystyle\overline{\lim_{n \to \infty}}cos(nx)>0,$$ and$$ \underline{\lim_{n \to \infty}}cos(nx)=0.$$
**edit**: @Lord Shark the Unknown points out in his answer that $\displaystyle\underline{\lim_{n\to \infty}} cos(nx)$ is actually a negative number(accurately speaking, $\displaystyle\underline{\lim_{n\to \infty} }cos(nx)=-1$.)

Comment: The latter isn't true when $x=2\pi$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown: Right, I'll edit my question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's think of this geometrically. $\cos nx$ is the $x$-coordinate
of the point $P_n=(\cos nx,\sin nx)$. The points $P_n$ lie on the unit circle. Each is obtained by rotating the previous point $x$ radians
anticlockwise.

We get a dichotomy. When $x$ is a rational multiple of $2\pi$, the sequence
$(P_n)$ is periodic. It takes a finite number of values, each infinitely
often. These points form the vertices of a regular $m$-gon, including
the point $(1,0)$. Therefore $\limsup\cos nx=1$.
If $m$ is even, then another vertex is $(-1,0)$
leading to $\liminf\cos nx=-1$. If $m$ is odd, then $\liminf\cos nx>-1$.

The other case is when $x$ is not a rational multiple of $2\pi$.
In this case the sequence $(P_n)$ is dense on the unit circle. Then
$\limsup\cos nx=1$ and $\liminf\cos nx=-1$.

Comment: Interesting perspective, but I think it requires some more technique to prove it strictly, I mean, using the properties of real numbers.